# What collection for quickly finding next elements?

Tags: java, collections

I have an object with a `currentDate` field. It will need to access `n` next workdays. I have a .csv file with all the workdays.

My current solution:

- Create an `ArrayList<LocalDate> workdays` from the .csv.
- Get `currentDateIndex` from `workdays.indexOf(currentDate)`.
- Get next `n` next days by iterating over `workdays.get(currentDateIndex + i)`.

What I don't like about it:

- No way of ensuring that `workdays` list is actually sorted, or doesn't have duplicates.
- O(n) complexity of `indexOf` method.

Is there a collection that will ensure that the workdays are unique and sorted and that can quickly return next `n` workdays when given the `currentDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TreeSet<LocalDate>`. That will keep the dates unique and sorted.

And you can obtain the next dates by calling `tailSet(E fromElement, boolean inclusive)`, and iterate over the returned `Set` to get the next `n` elements following a given element.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's exactly what I've been looking for! So if I want `n` next days, I just call `tailSet(currentDate, false)` and then call `iterator()` on the returned set or just use `first()` and `higher()` methods?

Comment: @momo you don't have to use `first()` and `higher()`. You just iterate over the `Set` returned by `tailSet()` (either with an explicit iterator or with the enhanced for loop), and break out of the loop after you obtained as many elements as you need.